# How can I run some command in iTerm session using the Python API

Tags: python, iterm2, iterm

I am trying to write a script that'd do some automation on my iTerm2.
I am using the [Python API for iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com/python-api/) since I know nothing about AppleScript.

What I need to do is basically, split the screen is 6 windows and run 6 microservices locally in each of them. I was successfully able to split the screen but I am unable to run a command in any of them.

Thanks in advance.

My existing code is as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import iterm2
# This script was created with the "basic" environment which does not support adding dependencies
# with pip.

async def main(connection):
    # Your code goes here. Here's a bit of example code that adds a tab to the current window:
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    window = app.current_terminal_window
    if window is not None:
        await window.async_create_tab()
    else:
        # You can view this message in the script console.
        print("No current window")

    leftOne = app.current_terminal_window.current_tab.current_session
    rightOne = await leftOne.async_split_pane(vertical=True)
    leftTwo = await leftOne.async_split_pane()
    leftThree = await leftOne.async_split_pane()
    rightTwo = await rightOne.async_split_pane()
    rightThree = await rightOne.async_split_pane()

    await leftOne.async_activate()
    await leftOne.as

iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

Comment: Run a command is easiest part but for last few days I'm scratching my head how to *run* a command and *capture* result...

Answer (score 7):

You can send keystrokes to [Sessions](https://www.iterm2.com/python-api/session.html) using the [`async_send_text()`](https://www.iterm2.com/python-api/session.html#iterm2.Session.async_send_text) method.

In your code, the following will execute a command:

```py
leftOne = app.current_terminal_window.current_tab.current_session
await leftOne.async_send_text('whoami\n')
```